# Amazon S3 load old version of edited page

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I have a application which storing static pages in amazon s3 bucket. When edit the page and save it using  AWS::S3::S3Object.store() methord. but when I refresh edited pages it randomly loading previous edited version of particular pages. Is it a bug of amazon s3 whick keeping previous version of pages? If yes how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your browser didn't cache the page?  Try CTRL-F5 to force a reload.

Comment: Have you tried in an entirely separate browser to see how it behaves?